# Angular2 rounting component as string

Tags: angular2-routing

Hi i have requirement where path and componentName is in string for me from backend

and response looks like

```
[{path:'admin',component:'adminComponent'},{path:'user',component:'def'}]
```

now i have created for loop and creating routes array as my requirement,My issue is its throwing error because component value is string for me.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([{"path":"admin","component":"adminComponent","children":[{"path":"ssd","component":"userComponent"}]}])
```

how can i make it work, if i remove double quotes manually its satrted working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand the problem correctly but you can use JSON.parse on the string. This way the quotes will be removed.

```
var res = '[{"path":"admin","component":"adminComponent","children":[{"path":"ssd","component":"userComponent"}]}]';
var test = JSON.parse(res);
```

Will give:

```
test = [{path:"admin", component:"adminComponent", children:[{ path:"ssd", component:"userComponent"}]}]
```

Comment: the issue is component value ie ("adminComponent") is in string thats why its throwing error if we put like this {path:"admin", component:adminComponent} its started working